# Share Data From Apple Watch to iPhone

Tags: iphone, swift, apple-watch, watchos

I am trying to Transfer Watch Data to the Application. I have tried to Research but the Tutorials are outdated. I am new to Watch development! I am thankful for any help I can get! :)

Trying to Pass Watch Button Text to iPhone Application

ON WATCH

let watchBatteryLevel = WKInterfaceDevice.current().batteryLevel
 self.button.setTitle(watchBatteryLevel)

ON IPHONE

Your Watch Battery is .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the watch app is not running it can't send a message to the iPhone app, and it cannot be launched from the iPhone app, so I don't know if your idea will make sense.

But you can send a message from a running watch app to the iPhone using the `WCSession` class functions.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession

`transferUserInfo` is one function that may do what you want